# Finishing predator challenges with proximity detonator

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

is there any way to finish the worst nightmare challenges (number 6 in particular) when I already upgraded to proximity detonator?

The proximity detonator seems to block the takedown option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dark Knight Predator encounter #6 is by far the hardest.

It is absolutely possible to perform the explosive gel takedown, the easiest place to get this challenge is in the Bank. To perform the explosive gel takedown, you need to **find a brick wall**, not a wooden one. You have to **place the gel on the opposite side of the wall**  from the enemy, when the gel explodes, it will send the fragments of the wall into the enemy killing them. There is no in game prompt for this happening and no visible verification that you succeeded until the stats rollup after the encounter.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, before you get the proximity detonator, it is 100% possible to get the explosive takedown with a weak wall son why take that ability away? All WB needed to do was shorten the required proximity to allow the enemy to get closer.

Also, in the other 'Batman Arkham' games once you have completed the Mau  story, rockstar did NOT remove all enemies from the buildings, there were still various rooms where you would be able to take on a predator encounter and still rooms where you would get into a brawl allowing you to complete any left over challenges, whereas WB decided that once you have completed the main story, there would be ZERO predator encounters, and ZERO indoor brawls, ok, so you could complete the brawling challenges outdoors if you found one of the very few areas where there are enough enemies for a 50+ combo plus all gadgets and special combo moves used, but you CANNOT complete the predator challenges at all, I am also stuck on "worst nightmare 6" because the only presator room available is in the church for the final "Black Mask" most wanted challenge (weak walls only) with the proximity detonator purchased, this means I have to choose between forever restarting the mission in the hope that I will someday by some luck get a weak wall takedown, or actually completing my most wanted mission, I've been at this for 3 days now so I choose the latter.